# After installing 5.18 kernel, a blinking cursor appears and cannot load into Desktop (22.04 LTS)

Tags: boot, grub2, nvidia, kernel

I'm very new to Linux so excuse me if this problem is trivial, however I wasn't able to solve it and I've spend two days trying to fix it. Also I couldn't find any post with a similar issue.

I want to update the Kernel to 5.18 so I can install Cuda, Cudnn and other tools that I need for my projects. I've followed simple tutorials, that tell you to just
`wget` followed by kernel.ubuntu.com link four times, then `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` . The installation works correctly, but when i reboot i just get a blinking cursor in the top left of my screen. Then, to repair it, I have to boot 5.15 kernel from grub menu, purge all packages related to 5.18 kernel and only then the computer boots normally. I have no idea why the newly installed kernel won't boot and would appreciate any help/advice on how to get it to work. I will happily provide any screenshots/logs that are needed to troubleshoot this, however I do not even know what to provide. The version of Ubuntu is 22.04.

Edit 1:
The exact packages i installed were:

```
https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.18/amd64/linux-headers-5.18.0-051800_5.18.0-051800.202205222030_all.deb
https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.18/amd64/linux-headers-5.18.0-051800-generic_5.18.0-051800.202205222030_amd64.deb
https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.18/amd64/linux-image-unsigned-5.18.0-051800-generic_5.18.0-051800.202205222030_amd64.deb
https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.18/amd64/linux-modules-5.18.0-051800-generic_5.18.0-051800.202205222030_amd64.deb
```

So the exact version was 5.18.0-051800

Edit 2: Here's the output of nvidia-smi, though after installing 515 version initially  nvidia-smi printed that the version was 510, I installed 515 again  (literally installed the exact same  thing in the update manager) and now when the PC boots it warns me of some kind of error (there's no info about the error, just asks if I want to send a bug report)

```
krzysztof@krzysztof-MS-7D25:~$ nvidia-smi
Sun Oct  2 11:38:35 2022       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 515.65.01    Driver Version: 515.65.01    CUDA Version: 11.7     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   43C    P0    98W / 350W |    328MiB / 12288MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      2029      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                 93MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2272      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell              101MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      4012      G   ...5/usr/lib/firefox/firefox      130MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
krzysztof@krzysztof-MS-7D25:~$
```

At the time of installation i did not use the proprietary nvidia drivers, so nvidia-smi outputted nothing, but I don't think the 5.18 kernel shouldn't be able to work without them, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: What version f Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: can you go to recovery mode after installation?

Comment: @David Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Comment: @Amirreza Recovery mode with the 5.18 does not work

Comment: Please edit the question and add that info.

Comment: It is unclear as to which exact version of 5.18 you are getting and from where. Try the [mainline PPA 5.18.19](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.18.19/) or/and list the exact commands you used and show us the `ls -l *.deb` of the files.

Comment: @DougSmythies Added the exact links i downloaded the packages from

Comment: O.K. great, so it was from mainline PPA. Yes, try the 5.18.19 I pointed to earlier, as it'll include 3 months of fixes. Note that you have to disable secure boot in BIOS to use mainline PPA kernels.

Comment: You might have to update the nvidia driver. Older nvidia driver with newer kernel might lead to your blinking cursor. What does the first line of `nvidia-smi`? say. Add that to your question, **not** in a comment

Comment: @DougSmythies Installing the 5.18.19 Kernel seems to have a similar effect, i get an error saying ```Dev loop1: unable to read RDB block 8 ``` and the PC still won't boot

Answer (score 2):

It is expected that Ubuntu doesn't boot with a mainline kernel.

There may be two reasons:

1. Secure Boot is enabled. Mainline kernels are not signed. So you have to disable Secure Boot.
2. Nvidia drivers don't build with a mainline kernel. You need to check if the dkms module is built. If it doesn't a patch to the module is needed to support a new kernel.

Comment: I checked and the securte boot is disabled. For the second answer, could you point me to a resource on how to do that?

Comment: It seems that the problem lies in the second option, as I have had secure boot disabled from the start