# Kernel 6.0.0 or 6.0.1 won't boot

Tags: kernel

I've tried to update the kernel on my Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, it's up to date and I've tried with mainline.

I'm using a Asus X670E Tuf Gaming with a Ryzen 9 7900X (i'm doing it to try to get the sensors infos)

Everytime I try a Kernel 6.x my computer hang when starting (during the kernel), last time I saw 4 or 5 lines. I've removed the "quiet splash" from the grub to get more details.

Any idea?

---

So I've tried 6.0.0, 6.0.1 and 6.1-rc1 without "quiet splash" and the system hang but it was at different lines.

6.0 : last line was a bluetooth line (my hardware was detected)

6.0.1 : last line was about switcheroo

6.1-rc1 : last line was "Reached target System Initialization"

so when it "hang" I could see some HDD activity, my HDD LED keep blinking like crazy, was like something was loading but nothing on my display.

So I was waiting about 10s and restarted to switch to old kernel (thru grub)

EDIT: Secure Boot is disabled and no nVIDIA drivers, I'm using the iGPU

Comment: What errors are you getting exactly? This is in ordert to have something to start thinking about the possible problem. Keep in mind using unsupported kernel versions in Ubuntu may not work and it's unlike anyone can offer some help.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1433273/after-installing-5-18-kernel-a-blinking-cursor-appears-and-cannot-load-into-des). Also try [mainline 6.1-rc1](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v6.1-rc1/). Did mainline 5.19 work O.K. for you?

Comment: One thing to remember is that mainline kernels are really for testing and not for production use.  They can be super buggy since they are usually still in development.  You are more than welcome to use them, but be prepared to submit bugs to help developers.

Comment: Is there a reason you want this bleeding edge kernel?

Comment: @David yes, it's a brand new motherboard and with the kernel included in the LTS I've got only one sensor... the nVME temp.

Comment: @ChanganAuto no real error during my boot, it just stop loading without an error message (i was waiting 10s before reset)